# Ajax iFrame: PHP will not add my different strings from SQL in my loop (to rebuild HTML code).

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, string, while-loop

I have an error with my PHP code below. I try to rebuild a list of  depending on some choices of the visitor and put it back in my HTML through an Ajax iframe.

The issue comes from this line when I try to add strings in the loop:

```
$tempr.='<option value=\"'.$donnees['name'].'\">'.$donnees['name'].'</option>');
```

Indeed, when I replace it by (for example):

```
$tempr.='<option value=\"loop\">loop</option>;
```

It works perfectly. I tried to separate the different strings, str_replace, put / everywhere but it doesn't work. I was wondering if my SQL database was too big... but it is very unlikely. Well I am lost.

Thanks  for our help!!!!

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT name FROM regions WHERE country = :country');
$req->execute(array('country' => $_SESSION['codepays']));
$donnees = $req->fetch();


$tempr='<select name=\"regionm\" id=\"regionm\" onchange=\"validregion();\">';

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT name FROM regions WHERE country = :country');
                $req->execute(array('country' => $_SESSION['codepays']));
                $donnees = $req->fetch();
                $i='0';
                while($donnees)
                    {   

                        $tempr.='<option value=\"'.$donnees['name'].'\">'.$donnees['name'].'</option>');    

                        $donnees = $req->fetch();
                    }

$tempr.='<option value=\"test\">test</option></select>';    

echo '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">'."\n";
echo 'var parDoc = window.parent.document;'."\n";
echo 'parDoc.getElementById("regionreplace").innerHTML="'.$tempr.'";'."\n";
echo "\n".'</script>';      

$req->closeCursor();
```

Comment: any reason you can't simply do `while($donnees = $req->fetch())`? If the fetch has nothing left, it assigns a false and causes the loop to exit. And if you're worried about DB size, then don't build a string with the results - output the results directly.

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem i could come up with is that you have character like `" < >` in your string. try this code:

```
 $tempr.='<option value=\"'.htmlspecialchars($donnees['name']).'\">'.$donnees['name'].'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$donnees = $req->execute(array('country' => $_SESSION['codepays']));
while(!$donnees->EOF)
{   
    $tempr.='<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($donnees->fields['name']).'">'.$donnees->fields['name'].'</option>';
    $req->MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work... I am starting to think that it may be some sort of restrictions.